# Simulating logging in to Windows without GUI

Tags: windows, authentication, automation

I am writing an automation the deployes several machines and installs several programs on them.

One of the steps a user would do manually is logging off and on to a windows computer as part of an installation process.

Can someone please point me to relevant links so i can understand how to simulate a logging in process into windows without a gui?

I mean i need to make the machine think someone logged in to it and i am using only powershell.

launching mstsc does not do the trick because i cant overcome the request for certificate (I need an automatic process but i did not find a way to silence the certificate warning)

I searched for a couple of days and could not find what I was looking for.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Does [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) suite your needs? it lets you log onto a remote machine (or yours, using a different user if you want). Don't know if it triggers the same events as a regular logon, though.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to use powershell.

Comment: So? PsExec is just a portable command-line utility. You can easily run it from the powershell, passing whatever arguments you need. I really don't know if it gives you the log-in effect you're looking for, but running it should not be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's just an idea. Perhaps you can first make the image of the machines with automatic logon , install the software and finally remove the automatic logon ?

This link has details about Automatic Logon
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315231

Comment: Actually I tried that, but some how, until I login to the machine with mstsc (with the same user defined in the Winlogon) it does not continue the same way it does when I do login. I wonder if some how I have to tell the machine it has a GUI to show its output for windows to run some of its processes. Does it make any sense? 
I really wish I could find a detailed description of the windows 7 logon process.